# How to change color in supreset charts

Tags: apache-superset

I am using superset to do the data visualiaztion, but cannot change color for funnel charts, is there any methods can do that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDfu9.png)

I have tried add this message in parameters, but it did not working .
"label_colors":{"reg":"#552288","open_account":"#5AAA46","wealth":"#CC7788"}